# PHP - check $get variable then clear div and include php file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am a noob in php. But I have something like this:

```
<div id="signupbox">
<!--A lot of stuff-->
</div>
```

so I have a php script just above this is check if a $get variable is `activation_success`, so I would echo a javascript to find #signupbox and change innerHTML, but I also want to include a file called `login.php` inside #signupbox.

The question is if I changed the div's innerHTML using javascript, the included .php file will also disappear.

**In what way can I change the innerHTML and include a .php file inside?**

I wanted to include `login.php` file because it is like a snippet so I can include it somewhere else and if I wanted to change, I can change the included file.

**What I kinda what to do is `echo('<script>$("#signupbox").html("Thank you!");</script>' . include("login.php"));`**

Comment: You could just add the content to `#box` rather then updating it?

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: with javascript, get the content already present in `#signupbox` and add the content of `login.php` to it. Then, replace the `innerHTML` with the whole.

Comment: what do you call a `$get` variable ? Is it `$_GET` ? This means that passing a variable in url would be enough to see the login form ?

Comment: You should also tag `jQuery` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** jQuery method :

```
html = $('#signupbox').html(); // save the previous html
$('#signupbox').load('login.php', function(){
   $(this).prepend(html); // add the previous html in the beginning
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm understanding correctly, you want to change the innerHTML of teh #box div but leave teh code generated by your include?

Why don't you make another, smaller div inside of #box and put only the stuff you want to disappear inside of it, then change just the inner div...

```
<div id="box">
<div id="innerBox">

<!--all the stuff that was in the #box, except for the include -->

</div>
<?php include "myinclude.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I am such an unintelligent monkey, that didn't came to my mind. Thank you. This question was stupid also.

Comment: you're welcome! there are no stupid questions, but please select this as your answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

include.php is not disappearing, php is server side language..
you code is erasing existing content and rewriting.
'`.html()`' will erase all contents inside the target eleiment, `include.php` contents will be erased while executing `.html()` function in clientside
while adding more content in javascript,

```
$('#signbox').append('Thank you!');
```

instead of

```
$('#signbox').html('Thank you!');
```

hope this will help.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad language organizing! I meant the box was a signup box so when the page get a variable it will change into a login box in the same page